# Segmentation Fault in the given Program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I often come across segmentation fault,and even though I know it occurs because of accessing restricted memory,I don't seem to get as to how do I rectify it.
I usually come across it, when I am calling another function.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
long int xyz(int n)
{
  vector<int> a;
  vector<int> b;


  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      cin>>a[i];
  }
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
     cin>>b[i];
  }
long int sum=0;

  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
   for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
       sum=sum+((a[j]-a[i])*max(b[i],b[j]));
    }
  }


 return sum;

}


int main() 
{
  int n;
  long int final;
  cin>>n;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {   int n;
      cin>>n;
      final=xyz(n);
      cout<<final<<endl;

   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `main` function, using two variables with the same name, type and used similarly, but with different scope, that is going to be a great source of confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use the indexing of vector or `[]` unless you have already initialized that index by declaring size or by `vec.push_back()` method!

Refer to these two pieces of code for clarification

This code will not run (segmentation error):

```
int main()
{
 vector<int> a; //not initialized so cant be indexed directly
 cin>>a[0];
 cout<<a[0];
 return 0;
}
```

This part will run without problem:

```
int main()
{
 vector<int> a(5); //size initialized upto 5, so if indexed at a point greater than 4 it will be error
 cin>>a[0];
 cout<<a[0];
 return 0;
}
```

**NOTE:** You can see a new type of error being printed if you use the `vec.at()` operator and that error will probably mean the same!

Give a try at this erroneous code:

```
int main()
{
 vector<int> a;
 cin>>a.at(0);
 cout<<a.at(0);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In this particular case, you have not *sized* your two vectors `a` and `b`.

They are constructed with zero size by default.

`vector<int> a(n);` gives you n elements. Make a similar change to `b` and all should be well.

The behaviour of using `[]` to access an element of a vector outside its range is undefined.

Comment: You can also push_back your numbers into the vectors

Comment: @Elried Using `push_back` (or `emplace_back`) is good if one doesn't know the size beforehand. Otherwise it's more effective to allocate the vector of the correct size and then just use normal array indexing.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I agree with that. In this particular set-up, using the `[]` or `at` is better. I just wanted to point out that an alternative exists.